# How can we poll the api with payload

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, polling

currently we have given a requirement that we are working with reactjs and we are hitting some backend api in java with a payload sometimes if there is huge data to retrive then we are getting timeout issue so we are thinking to implement polling so is polling possible by sending the payload to api in regular intervals until we get the required response.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, you can use a counter i to take the remainder of a Changshu, and you only need to set the timing to start the thread for query, and the problem can be solved.